# Enviar Informações do Link para uma Modal

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Estou desenvolvendo usando Bootstrap e ASP.NET MVC. Estou utilizando uma `Table` onde em cada linha tenho os botões Editar e Deletar. Estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach (var item in Model.REGISTRO_PERGUNTAS)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.ID_ARQUIVO</td>
            <td>@item.NUMERO_PERGUNTA</td>
            <td>@item.PERGUNTA</td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Editar", "Cadastros", 
                new { id = item.NUMERO_PERGUNTA}, 
                new { href = "#myModal", data_toggle = "modal" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Deletar","Deletar", "Cadastros", 
                new { id = item.NUMERO_PERGUNTA, pergunta = item.PERGUNTA }, 
                new { href = "#myModal", data_toggle = "modal" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</div>
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar os valores da linha que eu clicar em **Editar** ou **Deletar** e envia-los para a **modal** que eu criei?

Comment: Você quer chamar o método que devolve uma `ActionResult` no Controller e exibir uma modal em JS, é isso?

Comment: A modal já funciona como mostro no trecho de código acima quando clico em Editar ele gera o modal pra mim,mas não consigo pegar os valores da linha que eu cliquei. Daí de alguma forma retornar estes valores para o modal que acredito deva ser feito pela ActionResult.

Comment: Va verdade o retorno é pelo JS mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma mais prática que me ocorre é seres tu a chamar a *modal* sempre que precisas, fazendo-o dentro de uma função onde primeiro recolhes os dados que precisas e envias os mesmos para dentro da referida *modal*.

Retira do teu código a chamada da modal via atributo `data`:

```html
<a data_toggle="modal"/> <!-- não usar isto, vamos chamar com JavaScript -->
```

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // anexamos o evento à classe de CSS "modal-trigger"
  $('.modal-trigger').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // recolhemos os dados que pretendemos
    var $this  = $(this),
        $modal = $($this.data("target")),
        name   = $this.data("name"),
        action = $this.data("action"),
        title  = $this.closest("tr").find("td:first-child").html();

    // se a markup da modal existe, alteramos o que pretendemos
    if ($modal.size()==1) {

      $modal.find('#myModalLabel').html("A " + action + " " + title);
      $modal.find('.modal-body').html("Hei " + name + ", é para " + action + "?");
      // chamamos a modal
      $modal.modal('show');
    }
  });
 });
```

No código em cima e exemplo em baixo, o que é feito:

- Anexar evento de clique para que ao clicar num elemento da página que contenha a classe de CSS `modal-trigger` seja executado determinado código;
- Anulamos o comportamento por defeito desse elemento com uso do método [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/);
- Recolhemos dados presentes no botão com recurso ao método [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), adicionalmente recolhemos um texto da linha da tabela onde o botão se encontra;
- Verificamos se a *modal* está presente no DOM fazendo uma contagem do total de elementos com o ID da mesma, ver método [`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/);
- Se existe vamos alterar o título da *modal* e o conteúdo da mesma com os dados recebidos;
- Por fim, chamamos a modal fazendo uso do método [`.modal('show')`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

---

## Demonstrações

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.modal-trigger').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this  = $(this),
        $modal = $($this.data("target")),
        name   = $this.data("name"),
        action = $this.data("action"),
        title  = $this.closest("tr").find("td:first-child").html();

    if ($modal.size()==1) {

      $modal.find('#myModalLabel').html("A " + action + " " + title);
      $modal.find('.modal-body').html("Hei " + name + ", é para " + action + "?");

      $modal.modal('show');
    }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Coisas boas na vida
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm modal-trigger" data-target="#myModal" data-name="bubu" data-action="Editar">Editar</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm modal-trigger" data-target="#myModal" data-name="bubu" data-action="Apagar">Apagar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Fechar</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Siga...</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demonstração também no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/o31sv8fq/).

Answer (score 2):

Adicione atributos de `data-nome-do-atributo` no link da seguinte forma

```
<a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id-pergunta="1234">Editar</a>
```

e usar o evento on show do modal do bootstrap

```
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var idPergunta = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id-pergunta');
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="perguntaId"]').val(idPergunta);
});
```

Se utilizar frameworks JS para front end como Angular ou KnockoutJs seria ainda mais simples, mas acho que assim deva lhe atender

## [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwzdnrb7/)