# Abertura de Modal usando links diferentes para uma mesma linha da tabela

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
<table id="tabela">
    <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Produto</th>
         <th>Cliente</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>    
        <tr>
           <td id="produto1"><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Banana</a></td>
           <td id="cliente1"><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">José da Silva</a></td>                   
        </tr>                
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Como deu para perceber, na tabela possuo 2 links na mesma linha, um link deve mostrar através de um modal os dados do produto e o outro mostra os dados do cliente.
Para mostrar o modal do produto eu usei o seguinte script Jquery:

```
$(document).on("click","#tabela td a",function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var idproduto= $(this).parent().attr("id");    
    $('.modal-body').load('dados_produto.php?id='+idproduto);            
});
```

Até ai tudo funciona perfeitamente, o meu problema é: como fazer para criar uma nova interação com Jquery para o link do cliente abrir um modal para exibir o arquivo 'dados_cliente.php?id=+idcliente'?

Comment: [Nesse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38744/enviar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-link-para-uma-modal?rq=1) contém uma resposta bem semelhante para o que você precisa.

Comment: Nossa... Não consegui fazer funfar através do post recomendado

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:
No link de produtos, o id vai com um nome que indica a coluna referente a informação e concatento com um separador '-' mais o valor do id onde o usuário clicou, ficando assim:
'cliente-1' ou 'produto-5'

No Jquery eu dou um split e separo o campo que identifica o a posição na tabela e o valor do id clicado.

```
$(document).on("click","#tabela td a",function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var linkClicadoComId = $(this).parent().attr("id").split('-');
    var tipo = linkClicadoComId[0];
    var id = linkClicadoComId[1];

    if(tipo == 'produto'){
        $('.modal-body').load('dados_produto.php?id='+id);
    }
    if(tipo == 'cliente'){
        $('.modal-body').load('dados_cliente.php?id='+id);
    }
});
```

Ficou fera, quem quiser tá ai a resolução.